# Post request to Spotify API

Tags: javascript, node.js, spotify

I'm using Node.js to build an website where I can skip tracks and queue songs in Spotify (project for learning nodeJS and Javascript)

This code in inside index.html.

```
document.getElementById('skip-song').addEventListener('click', function(){
    $.post({
        url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/next',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
        },
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response.headers);
        }
    });
});
```

But, when I look on the console of the browser, it reads:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) : 8888/[object%20Object]

Question here is: should I be sending a request to the localhost and route it to spotify api or should I send a request directly to spotify like I'm doing in this code?

If it's the second, I can't really figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: I have used php on my server side, and it is the server who is making the request to spotify. In this way I can cache this requests if there are repeated requests... hope it helps!

Comment: But can't I send the request straight from the client to spotify? I was using express on the server side, but I ran into problems routing the request as well.

Comment: I think yes, it is possible. Did you pass the secret and clint id before the token? Did you check: https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node

Comment: Yeah! I took a look at it, but this library doesn't include all the player endpoints, I wanted to be able to skip a song as well, so I was trying to do it myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found out! I'm still not sure why that was not working, but by changing the code to the following it worked.

```
document.getElementById('skip-song').addEventListener('click', function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/next',
    headers: {'Authorization': "Bearer " + access_token}
  });
});
```